# CORS in .NET 6 AllowAllOrigin not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors, private-network-access

I am trying to allow requests from other domains to my app in `Startup.cs` (in .NET Core 6).

In `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`:

```
services.AddCors(options => options.AddDefaultPolicy(policy =>
                  {
                      policy
                      //.AllowAnyOrigin() // <- I also tried this
                      .AllowAnyMethod()
                      .AllowAnyHeader()
                      .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true); // <- instead of this
                  }));
```

I also tried `AddPolicy` instead of `AddDefaultPolicy`.

In `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)`:

```
app.UseCors(_corsAllPolicy);
```

I am still getting

> Access to script at 'https://localhost:44306/dist/js/build.js' from
> origin 'http://customdomain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The
> request client is not a secure context and the resource is in
> more-private address space `local`.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Please show the request and reponse headers of a request that fails

Comment: @nickornotte Can you try the code from this comment? https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/40869#issuecomment-1078903375

Comment: BTW it's very weird to have code from a .com domain trying to access a js file on localhost. You should also check whether you can prevent this.

Comment: See https://developer.chrome.com/blog/private-network-access-update/

Comment: @NineBerry I am testing the localhost script is working. I happen to be testing it on a live domain. I don't need to prevent it, localhost won't be visible from internet so there is nothing to secure.

Comment: It looks like the hint given by @jub0bs was the closest to the issue cause - I am using Chrome 108

Answer (score -1):

Make Sure you've called  `app.UseCors` before  `app.UseStaticFiles`

And if you try with  the default policy:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(
        policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins("");
        });
});
```

just call:

```
app.UseCors();
```

don't add any parameters in the method,
And you could check the related [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0) for more details

if you still got the error,please provide the minimal codes that could reprodce your error

Comment: I have `app.UseCors` before `app.UseStaticFiles` and your code is fine. Although I am following the documentation as you can see in my example...

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved, I should have paid more attention to the error comment:

> *The request client is not a secure context*

Basically the domain was not secure and was calling script that was under secure domain. I am calling now from a secure domain and it is working.

Thanks for reassuring me that my code was correct :)

Comment: Even if both sites are accesses using https, this will stop working again in one of the upcoming browser releases. See the link posted by jub0bs

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. I am solving the current problem though, not the future one so there is no reason to downgrade the solution answer ;)

Comment: Also what I am doing is just testing, it won't be permanent solution (to access private network) so I'll simply keep in mind the restriction of accessing the private network @NineBerry